# How to make a custom control and component for Metro development?

Tags: c#, components, controls, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I'd like to get ahead of the pack and start making some custom C# controls and components for Metro (Win8), but I can't find any documentation or blog posts on how to start, or even if it's possible right now.

Are metro controls just WPF controls? I'm not yet a WPF developer; creating a custom user control looks straightforward, but that project type doesn't exist in the Windows 8 developer preview. So, are WPF custom user controls (VS2010) the project type I should use for creating my Metro controls? Beyond that, I can't find any documentation on how to create a component for use in WPF/Metro; can you create one, or would it just be a custom user control that isn't visible? (I was hoping for some type of component container like the one winforms use; are components for Metro now only class libraries, and don't include designer support anymore?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 native custom control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281845/windows-8-native-custom-control)

Answer (score 1):

It's ... very difficult right now. There's no way to override OnRender or the like for a control, ie to create code to render a control with a custom appearance. However, you can create a custom template. Anything you can do in the template is legal, and that's how you have to approach custom controls.

One other option is to generate your UI using either raster (Bitmap) or vector (Windows.UI.Xaml.Shape?) components directly and build up your UI like that. Bleh.

Win8 Metro is a lot like WPF, but it isn't a subset. Similar but very different. Many WPF controls didn't make the transition to Win8 Metro; the same level of rendering control isn't available; and some system features (like advanced font rendering) aren't there. All this might change in coming releases, but right now it looks like Microsoft is trying to restrain developers from creating custom UI controls.

Comment: thanks; and regarding components, do you know if I'm limited exclusively to class libraries, or is there some way to make an actual component (designer/toolbox support)?

Comment: You can get Expression Blend support for your components; they're packaged up differently but there's stuff there. Basically choose the Win8 MetaData format as your build target.

Comment: Can you explain more about how to make a custom template? I don't see any project type like that in the Win8 DP VS11 Express new project dialog, or any output type.

Comment: I mean in the XAML markup; it's not a project type. I know from WPF that there's a lot that can be tweaked by editing a control's template, although the Win8 documentation is still lacking.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help; I think I'll limit my work to components for now. Is there any way to get the component to show up in the toolbox in Metro?