# Windows 8 native custom control

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, custom-controls

I want to make a custom control with the Windows 8 API in C# so that it will run on an RT app distributed through the store.

I looked through what I can add to a project and found **Templated Control** and **User Control**. Both allow me to organize other controls and some logic into a new control for reusability.

But this isn't what I want. I want to be able to custom paint and create controls. I would be shocked if they removed this but am honestly uncertain if I can. I'm basically looking for what class to inherit from and what method / event to override to let me draw the control myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to use the **Templated Control** option that I wasn't aware of before.  Essentially my custom control has a canvas that I 'paint' with objects (lines, images, etc.) by adding them as children and manipulating them in events.

[This tutorial](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/12/06/Building-Custom-Controls-for-Windows-8-Store-apps.aspx) helped me figure out what I was doing.

I've seen other people say they created a rectangle and painted it with a special Brush, either a ImageBrush (where they drew an image in the background) or a DrawingBrush.

Hopefully one of these two approaches can help anyone looking for the same thing I was.